# What is the way to access private S3 bucket files using nginx as proxy?

Tags: nginx, amazon-web-services, proxy, reverse-proxy, amazon-s3

I have a website and an S3 bucket with numerous images, which should not be accessible directly from any machine with a direct URL.

Those images will be shown on different website pages for ONLY registered users.

I have tried to find a simple way to access S3 bucket files with a specific cookie or additional header, but can't find that. Is it not possible?

Yes, an additional header is impossible to set in the browser, but I could make a proxy in Nginx for this goal (the proxy can set up those specific cookies or add headers when passing a request to S3). But it's still not clear how to enable URL access for S3 bucket files from either specific IP address (my Nginx proxy address) or using a specific cookie or specific header.

Could you help me, please?

Answer (score 2):

[Restricting Access to Specific IP Addresses](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-bucket-policies.html#example-bucket-policies-use-case-3)

Answer (score 1):

You should use [presigned URLs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html) to ensure only authorised users can access content on S3. This technique also works for [CloudFront](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-signed-urls.html), in which case you use an [Origin Access Identity](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-restricting-access-to-s3.html) to prevent direct S3 access.